# Rails form with ajax and non-ajax buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ajax-on-rails

I have a form_for an @object with two buttons.

While the first button renders the 'show action', the second button renders the same form again. So I'd like the latter to be ajax-handled.

Is it possible to have a non-ajax button and an ajax button in the same form or do I have to change strategy?

Maybe I need a form_for with 'remote: true' so that both the buttons are ajax but then, how would I manage the first button to render the proper 'show view'?

Or maybe the only real solution is to have two different forms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to hook onto the buttons `onClick` event, remove the `data-remote="true"` attribute, submit the form and add `data-remote="true"` again. I dont know if this is really the best way but it should work.

```
function sendWithoutAjax() {
  $('my_form_id').removeAttr("data-remote");
  $('my_form_id').submit();
  $('my_form_id').data( "remote", "true" );
}
```

Something like this...

Comment: Problem with that : if the submit button is actually an `<input>` with a value (commit message), using form.submit() will NOT pass the input commit message of the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach would be to use the [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin. Then you can just create the form to submit to your non-ajax action, and the ajax functionality will be attached to the submit button itself:

```js
$(".ajax_submit_button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").ajaxSubmit({
    // options go here
    ...
  });
  return false;
});
```